# How to build MFEM and GLVis in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, makefile

I want to build serial version of MFEM and GLVis in Windows. But there is not enough examples on the Net. Also, I want to call GLVis as a library and compile it on Windows. It is recommended to compile it with CMake for Windows, but sufficient explanation is not given. There is the link that i followed: [mfem](https://mfem.org/building/). I am using git bash and MinGW for this. But I got this error message (some of them):

```
user MINGW64 /c/mfem/mfem-4.6
$ MinGW32-make serial -j

general/tic_toc.cpp:123:18: error: 'CLOCK_MONOTONIC' was not declared in this scope

makefile:456: recipe for target 'linalg/vector.o' failed
MinGW32-make[1]: *** [linalg/vector.o] Error 1
makefile:456: recipe for target 'linalg/constraints.o' failed
MinGW32-make[1]: *** [linalg/constraints.o] Error 1
makefile:456: recipe for target 'linalg/solvers.o' failed
MinGW32-make[1]: *** [linalg/solvers.o] Error 1
MinGW32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/mfem/mfem-4.6'
makefile:497: recipe for target 'serial' failed
MinGW32-make: *** [serial] Error 2
```

How can I solve this problem?